# distance matrix google maps gives wrong distance between two locations while using in curl php code

Tags: google-maps, distance, google-distancematrix-api

```php
$userLat1=51.509904342252;
$userLong1= -0.13413459062576; 
$userLat2=51.517618;
$userLong2= -0.096778;   
$userLat3=51.5017863;
$userLong4= -0.0536478;    



$userLat=51.509904342252;
$userLong= -0.13413459062576;
$lat2=51.495042;
$long2= -0.131382;

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$userLat.",".$userLong."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&sensor=false";
    //$response = file_get_contents($url);
                $ch = curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                  $response = curl_exec($ch);
                  curl_close($ch);
                  $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
```

When I mark pins on map at locations

```php
$userLat1=51.509904342252;
$userLong1= -0.13413459062576; 
$userLat2=51.517618;
$userLong2= -0.096778;   
$userLat3=51.5017863;
$userLong4= -0.0536478;    



$userLat=51.509904342252;
$userLong= -0.13413459062576;
$lat2=51.495042;
$long2= -0.131382;
```

,I can clearly see on map that which marker is near to $lat2 &$long2.

But when i use above code to get distance between two positions mentioned above,It gives me incorrect data..
In a way it gives more distance value for nearest station ,which i am seeing on map nearest to lat2 & long2 position on map.

Similarly if i use above code to get distance between

```php
$userExtralat2=21.118692, 
$userExtralong2=73.117554
```

&

```php
$lat2=51.495042;
$long2= -0.131382;
```

google provides Distance in Days & hours..

How to get Distance in km using Distancematrix Api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I get from the distance matrix is (modifying [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix)):

```
origin[0]:51.509904,-0.134135
origin[0]:A4, London W1J, UK to destination[0]:51.509904,-0.134135: 1 m in 1 min
origin[0]:A4, London W1J, UK to destination[1]:51.517618,-0.096778: 4.1 km in 15 mins
origin[0]:A4, London W1J, UK to destination[2]:51.501786,-0.053648: 7.4 km in 23 mins
origin[0]:A4, London W1J, UK to destination[3]:51.495042,-0.131382: 2.8 km in 9 mins
origin[0]:A4, London W1J, UK to destination[4]:21.118692,73.117554: 11,411 km in 7 days 5 hours
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/656dzL7d/)

The distance is returned in the results (at least in the Google Maps Javascript API v3, should be in the web service as well):   `results[j].distance.text`

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];
var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';
var locations;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  $userLat1 = 51.509904342252;
  $userLong1 = -0.13413459062576;
  $userLat2 = 51.517618;
  $userLong2 = -0.096778;
  $userLat3 = 51.5017863;
  $userLong4 = -0.0536478;

  // $userLat = 51.509904342252;
  // $userLong = -0.13413459062576;
  $lat2 = 51.495042;
  $long2 = -0.131382;
  $userExtralat2 = 21.118692,
    $userExtralong2 = 73.117554

  locations = [new google.maps.LatLng($userLat1, $userLong1),
    new google.maps.LatLng($userLat2, $userLong2),
    new google.maps.LatLng($userLat3, $userLong4),
    // new google.maps.LatLng($userLat, $userLong),
    new google.maps.LatLng($lat2, $long2),
    new google.maps.LatLng($userExtralat2, $userExtralong2)
  ];
}

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: locations,
    destinations: locations,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
    deleteOverlays();
    outputDiv.innerHTML += "origin[0]:" + locations[0].toUrlValue(6) + '<br>';
    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        // addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "origin[" + i + "]:" + origins[i] + ' to destination[' + j + ']:' + locations[j].toUrlValue(6) /* destinations[j] */ + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#content-pane {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
#outputDiv {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="content-pane">
  <div id="inputs">
    <p>
      <button type="button" onclick="calculateDistances();">Calculate distances
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</div>
```